# SerialDataReceivedEventHandler is not firing

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to write a code to receive from serial port using C#.

I'm using VSPC utitility to generate bridge from two ports COM27 and COM28
when I write to COM27 to send the data to COM28 and I can see it using Putty connection, but when I tryed to make a program using the following code it doesn't work and the SerialDataReceivedEventHandler is not firing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace csh_serial2_pic
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        foreach (string port in ports)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(port);
        }
    }
    //
    string t;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
        sErial(t);
    }
    // Method
    SerialPort sp;
    void sErial(string Port_name)
    {
        //ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(2, 4); 
        sp = new SerialPort(Port_name, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        sp.ReadTimeout = 1000;
        sp.WriteTimeout = 1000;
        sp.ReadBufferSize = 4096;
        sp.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;

        //

        sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandeler);
        sp.Open();
        sp.DtrEnable = true;
        sp.RtsEnable = true;

        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        //sp.Close();



    }
    //
    private void DataReceivedHandeler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender ;

        Debug.Print("receiving!");
        string data = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("received: " + data);
        Debug.Print(data);

        string w = sp.ReadLine();

        if (w != string.Empty)
        { 
            Invoke(new Action (() => richTextBox1.AppendText(w)));

        }

    }
}
}
```

so any one can help me in this issue

Comment: Make sure your PuTTY settings for the COM port match that same 9600-8n1. Otherwise a character will probably not register as being received. Just to make sure, the handler never fires? Or does it block on `sp.ReadLine()`? With that timeout value set it shouldn't block for more than 1 sec, but check anyway. Finally, if the read does timeout you'll get an exception that you're not set up to handle.

Comment: PuTTy has a knack for making it look like it works because it displays the character you type on the keyboard.  You have to run two instances of it and what you type in one should appear in the other.  Not wiring the ports is a typical reason for failure, a null modem is required.

Comment: Thanks For your replay. The configuration is the same as the Putty. and as you see in the code that the debug message didn't appear to me this mean that the event not fired.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a port without setting buffer sizes,  timeouts, rts/dts enables If you mess with the default values without full understanding of why you are doing so, you may shoot yourself in the foot. For example, if the read times out after only one second (1000 ms), you may not receive any data before it times out.

Is the data you are sending text? if not, you may receive data that is not convertable to a string, and so no output will be generated.

Also you are reading data for debugging, and then trying to read another line of data to display. After the first read, the buffer will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I already use the port with the default configuration without adjusting the buffer size and the timeouts but it didn't work. and I puted the debugging reading lines to test but also it didn't work.